# How to use Log4j 2 with flink application

Tags: log4j2, apache-flink

As I do this below

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api-scala_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

It does'nt work to use log4j2 in Flink application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log4j2-slf4j binding log4j-slf4j-impl-2.3.jar routes calls from slf4j to log4j2. So add this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```